# Read BMP file and rotate

Tags: c, bitmap

I'm trying to read a BMP file and save it in a buffer with 2 dimension in order to rotate it in a right angle. However, the final file is not correct and cannnot be displayed. What is the problem in the following code?

```
#include <fstream.h>
#include <iostream.h>

int main() {
    long int width=686;
    long int height=800 ;
/* open file */
    FILE * bitmap_file= fopen("filename.bmp", "rb");
    if(!bitmap_file) {
        printf("Could not find file.\n");
        fclose(bitmap_file);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("File opened.\n");
    typedef struct buffer1
    {         
        int red;
        int green;
        int blue;
    } buffer1;
    static buffer1 buffer_bitmap1[686][800];
    fseek(bitmap_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    int count=0;
    for(int i = 0; i <8; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j <6; ++j){
            fread(&buffer_bitmap1[j][i].red , 1, 1, bitmap_file);    /*for rotate bmp exchange the width with height in matrix.*/
            fread(&buffer_bitmap1[j][i].green, 1, 1, bitmap_file);
            fread(&buffer_bitmap1[j][i].blue, 1, 1, bitmap_file);
            count=count+8;
            fseek(bitmap_file,count, SEEK_CUR);     /*move pointer*/
        }
    }
    fclose(bitmap_file);
    FILE *bitmap_file1= fopen("filename.bmp", "a");
    count=0;
    fseek(bitmap_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char * a ="a";
    for(int i = 0; i <6; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j <8; ++j) {
            fwrite(&buffer_bitmap1[i][j],1,1,bitmap_file1);
            fwrite(&buffer_bitmap1[i][j].blue,1,1,bitmap_file1);
            fwrite(&buffer_bitmap1[i][j].green,1,1,bitmap_file1);
            count=count+8;
            fseek(bitmap_file, 8, SEEK_CUR);     /*move pointer*/
        }
    }
    fclose(bitmap_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like pure C language why it is tagged C++?

Comment: So, you include `fstream.h` and `iostream.h` (which should both not exist) and don't use them at all. Then you use a bunch of implicit declared functions, since you didn't include `cstdio`. Ouch. Beside that, could you provide pictures which show your desired result and your actual result?

Comment: Defining structs in function scope? Now that's something funky!

Answer (score 3):

At least, You can not simply read a BMP file from the beginning as it has a [BMP Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

The first of all you need to read a header int order to get the BMP parameters (image size, data offset, bits per pixel etc.)

The second, in order to rotate the image and to be able to see the result, you also will need to modify the header.